Problem in running Xdebug version 2 with PhpStorm
I have a problem with the working of Xdebug 2.1.29 with PhpStorm, PHP version 7.1.
My configuration xdebug.ini:
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_connect_back=off
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.extended_info=on

Dockerfile
FROM php:7.1-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libc-client-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libxml2-dev libkrb5-dev wget && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl\
    && docker-php-ext-install gettext soap imap pdo_mysql exif zip gd \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.9.8  \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug;

And I tried to set servers in PhpStorm and use path mappings. Unfortunately PhpStorm does not detect the session.
The best part is that when I change PHP version to 7.2 and Xdebug to 3.1.6 everything works fine.
Xdebug 3 working config:
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.log_level=0
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM

Why Xdebug 2 and PHP 7.1 don't want to work?


Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and see what it has to say. Maybe it's not trying to connect at all... 2) Double check that Xdebug is enabled in your PHP. Maybe it's not loaded. 3) Make sure to check it for the same env as you are trying to debug: CLI or a web page (as some setups can have different php.ini for them) 4) Better tell Xdebug v2 to use the same port 9003 as v3 uses. 9000 is also used by some other apps: php-fpm for example (one of the reasons why the default one got changed in v3)


Restarting the computer helped, also topic can be closed
